# JPA @Query annotation for update query (oracle sql developer) -- org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have one repository file shared the source code for the same and one controller class through which I make a call to that @query function for one the update statement. I want to update one column data into my Oracle database for which I have written JPA update @query and defined the function into one of the repository files hence making a call from one of my controller class getting could not execute the query.

**Repository file**

```
package com.sid.demo.repository;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import com.sid.demo.model.hindalco_model;

public interface update_password extends JpaRepository<hindalco_model,Integer> 
{   
    @Query(value="update USER_REGISTRATION set password = :password WHERE user_name = :user_name and email = :email",nativeQuery=true)
    List<String> findbyuser_update(@Param("password") String password,String user_name,String email);   
}
```

**Controller class**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/update_password",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String update_password(@RequestParam String password)
    {
        //String rnumber_verified=randomNumber;
        //int random_otp_verified=Integer.parseInt(rnumber_verified);



        //System.out.println("update query string value = "+hindalco_user_login12);
        System.out.println("user_name outside try = "+user_name12);
        System.out.println("email outside try = "+password12);
        try
        {
            System.out.println("user_inside try = "+user_name12);
            System.out.println("email inside try = "+password12);

            update_password_repo.findbyuser_update(password,user_name12,password12);
            return "Entered password successfully updated"; 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return"Iam sorry entered password did not match "+e;
        }

    }
```

**Model Class**

```
package com.sid.demo.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="user_registration")
public class hindalco_model
{
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private int user_id;

    @Column(name="user_name")
    private String user_name;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getUser_name() {
        return user_name;
    }

    public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "hindalco_model [user_id=" + user_id + ", user_name=" + user_name + ", email=" + email + ", password="
                + password +"]";
    }



}
```

I just wanted to write JPA @query to update one of my column data and for that, I want to pass function call from controller class to that repository file which contains @query annotation function definition which will automatically get convert into hibernate query through the compiler and hence in oracle database the data will be updated.

Answer (score 5):

```
@Transactional
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query(value="update USER_REGISTRATION set password = ?1 WHERE user_name = ?2 and email = ?3",nativeQuery=true)
void findbyuser_update(String password,String user_name,String email);
```

The `@Modifying` annotation is used to enhance the @Query annotation to execute not only SELECT queries but also INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and even DDL queries.

Comment: Hibernate: UPDATE DATABASE_NAME.USERS_TABLE SET PASSWORD = ? WHERE USER_NAME = ?
2019-03-13 11:54:55.183  WARN 26760 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1002, SQLState: 24000
2019-03-13 11:54:55.183 ERROR 26760 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

Comment: @SAMUELBARKLEY Hello, please share your updated query you have written

Comment: @Transactional
     @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
     @Query(value="UPDATE MINES.HMG_ZEPHYR_USERS SET PASSWORD = :password WHERE USER_NAME = :user_name",nativeQuery=true)
     List<String> findbyuser_update(@Param("password") String password,String user_name);

Comment: @SAMUELBARKLEY update query will not return List<String> so change it to void and try again if it does help then you might need to set autocommit to false

Answer (score 4):

For modifying queries (update, delete, insert) you need to use the annotation `@Modifying`.

Also, your query doesn't return anything so your method should probably return `void`.

And while not necessary it is always a good idea to name a method according to what it actually is doing.

All this results in:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value="update USER_REGISTRATION set password = :password WHERE user_name = :user_name and email = :email",nativeQuery=true)
void updatePassword(@Param("password") String password,String user_name,String email);
```

Comment: Hibernate: UPDATE ss.sid SET PASSWORD = ? WHERE USER_NAME = ?
2019-03-13 11:54:55.183  WARN 26760 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1002, SQLState: 24000
2019-03-13 11:54:55.183 ERROR 26760 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

Comment: @Transactional is also required.

Comment: @VXp while a transaction might be required `@Transactional` is not required on the method.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the flow is like `Controller` -> `Service` -> `Dao`. So you can create a Service which will call the respective dao/repository. Also, please check  [this](https://javabeat.net/spring-data-jpa-query/)  link.